# select columns with condition on dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
    GPA1PP GPB1PP C D E  GPAB12PP
0
1
2
3
```

Now I want to select some columns

```
a_test=df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("A")]
b_test=df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("B")]
```

1.
Both a_test and b_test have "GPAB12PP" columns but I want to it only appears in the a_test dataframe. How can I do?

2.

C D E columns not be selected. Can I use "minus" to select them?

For example in R

```
c_test=df[:,-c(1,2,6)]
print(c_test)
  C D E
0
1
2
3
```

Does python be the same?

Thanks

Comment: About 1... you said you want "GPAB12PP" in `a_test` only. What about the other columns? And what should be selected in `b_test`?

Answer (score 2):

1. for the first question you can use this:

   ```
   a_test=df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith("A")]
   b_test=df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith("B")]
   ```
2. for the second question you can use this:

   ```
   c_test=df.loc[:,~(df.columns.str.contains('A') | df.columns.str.contains('B'))]
   ```

Comment: sorry,  I made a mistake. A and B is not begin or end.

Comment: you can simply use these lines of code :
a_test=df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("A")]
b_test=df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("B") & ~df.columns.str.contains('A')]